# Configure the auth-method of the web.xml externally to the EAR file

Tags: jakarta-ee, properties, system, jboss7.x, web.xml

Currently trying, without success, to configure the AUTH-METHOD element of the web.xml externally (through system properties loaded during JBoss 7.1.1 startup).

I thought this would do the job :

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>${prest_authMethod}</auth-method>
    <realm-name>PREST Authentication</realm-name>
</login-config>
```

But it crashes during deployment :

```
12:56:01,773 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig] (MSC service thread 1-4) Cannot configure an authenticator for method ${prest_authMethod}
```

Is there a way to access system properties from web.xml ? Or any other way to configure the AUTH-METHOD with external configuration ?
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, this configuration does not work anymore on JBoss 7 but was working on JBoss 5 and 6. Have a look at https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AS7-3195. The reason is "outside of EE specs".

However, due to a high number of community complaints, this should comes back in EAP 7.1.2 and 7.2 GA (the community version 7.1.2 was not built as a released version, the patch should comes with 7.2).

Answer (score 0):

I tried to access properties this way by setting them in the system-properties section of the standalone.xml. It crashed and burned doing it this way which is a pity.

Setting it at server startup with a -Dproperty=myProperty did work though.

By the way I am using Jboss EAP 6.0 which is practically the same version.